# Log4j2 java properties based configuration not deleting old files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

The below log4j2 configuration is failing to delete my old files.

```
# Rolling file appender
log4j2.appender.rolling.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
log4j2.appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
log4j2.appender.rolling.fileName = ${karaf.data}/log/karaf.log
log4j2.appender.rolling.filePattern = ${karaf.data}/log/karaf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log.zip
# uncomment to not force a disk flush
# log4j2.appender.rolling.immediateFlush = false
log4j2.appender.rolling.append = true
log4j2.appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.rolling.layout.pattern = ${log4j2.pattern}
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 5MB
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
# uncomment to set max number of files to create per day
# log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.max = 10
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.basePath = ${karaf.data}/log
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxdepth = 1
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = karaf-*.log.zip
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfLastModified
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.age = 5m
```

My log files are being generated correctly as setup by the Time Based and Size Based policies but I cannot figure out why the files aren't being deleted. Everything seems to be correct and I am getting no errors in my logs.

I have no leading or trailing spaces.

I've wasted so much time trying to debug this. The official log4j2 documentation is woeful as it doesn't give java properties based config examples.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This helped me fixed an issue with my Karaf logging config. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing:

```
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = karaf-*.log.zip
```

to

```
log4j2.appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = *.zip
```

Looks like the old regex pattern isn't being interpreted properly which is extremely strange since it is definitely correct.